# Get all the rows with same values in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

So, suppose I have this 2D array in python

```
a = [[1,2]
     [2,3]
     [3,2]
     [1,3]]
```

How do get all array entries with the same row value and store them in a new matrix. 
For example, I will have

```
b = [1,2]
    [1,3]
```

after the query.

My approach is `b = [a[i] for i in a if a[i][0] == 1][0]]`
  but it didn't seem to work?

I am new to Python and the whole index slicing thing is kind confusing. Thanks!

Comment: `b = [x for x in a if x[0] == 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy), you *can* perform this task with NumPy arrays. First define your array:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2],
              [2, 3],
              [3, 2],
              [1, 3]])
```

For *all* unique values in the first column, you can use a dictionary comprehension. This is useful to avoid duplicating operations.

```
d = {i: a[a[:, 0] == i] for i in np.unique(a[:, 0])}

{1: array([[1, 2],
           [1, 3]]),
 2: array([[2, 3]]),
 3: array([[3, 2]])}
```

Then access your array where first column is equal to 1 via `d[1]`.

For a single query, you can simply use `a[a[:, 0] == 1]`.

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me! but I am wondering if there is simpler way to access the elements?

Comment: @JimmyW, You really need to define `simpler`. There is no simpler way I know of than `a[a[:, 0] == 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

The `for i in a` syntax gives you the actual items in the list..so for example:

```
list_of_strs = ['first', 'second', 'third']
first_letters = [s[0] for s in list_of_strs]
# first_letters == ['f', 's', 't']
```

What you are actually doing with `b = [a[i] for i in a if a[i][0]==1]` is trying to index an element of a with each of the elements of a. But since each element of `a` is itself a list, this won't work (you can't index lists with other lists)

Something like this should work:

```
b = [row for row in a if row[0] == 1]
```

Bonus points if you write it as a function so that you can pick which thing you want to filter on.

If you're working with arrays a lot, you might also check out the [numpy library](http://www.numpy.org/). With numpy, you can do stuff like this.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2], [2,3], [3,2], [1,3]])
b = a[a[:,0] == 1]
```

The last line is basically indexing the original array `a` with a boolean array defined inside the first set of square brackets. It's very flexible, so you could also modify this to filter on the second element, filter on other conditions (like `> some_number`), etc. etc.